# How to accomplish one-to-many mapping using XSLT

Tags: xml, html, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a question regarding XSLT.
I understand that XSLT can be used to transform a XML to another XML.
Let's say there is an xml file called `data.xml`

```
<data>
  <field>
    <attr>Attribute 1</attr>
    <attr>Attribute 2</attr>
  </field>
</data>
```

supposed there is an xsl file called `transform.xsl` and `another.xsl`

Both files define how to transform `data.xml` in a similar manner.

`transform.xsl` includes `another.xsl`

Let's say I want to let `transform.xsl` to transform to `foo.html` and let another.xsl's transformation to append on `foo.html`, does anybody know how to accomplish that by any chance???

Another problem I'm having right now is that because `<xsl:include>` can override a template, only one will take effect. Is it possible to make same `<xsl:template>` to call multiple times??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modes to distinguish the processing steps (`<xsl:template match="field" mode="m1">...</xsl:template>` and `<xsl:template match="data"><xsl:apply-templates select="field" mode="m1"/></xsl:template>`) but of course that requires authoring the `another.xsl` or editing it to use a mode.

As a second though, as you have tagged your question as XSLT 2.0, there you additionally have the option to use `<xsl:next-match/>`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match.

To give you an example of working with modes, the main stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:include href="test2013080802.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>Example</h1>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="field[1]" mode="thead"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="list"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field" mode="thead">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="thead"/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field/*" mode="thead">
      <th><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field/*">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the included then uses a mode named `list`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="list">
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>Example</h1>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data" mode="list">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field" mode="list">
      <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="#current"/>
      </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field/*" mode="list">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output then is

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>attr</th>
               <th>attr</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Attribute 1</td>
               <td>Attribute 2</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <ul>
         <li>Attribute 1, Attribute 2</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```